# issues navigating to another page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, navigation

Here is my MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
            <RowDefinition  />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0">This is Page 1</Label>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Next" Click="Next_Click" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have another page called Page2

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApplication1.Page2"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    Title="Page2">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
            <RowDefinition  />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0">This is Page 2</Label>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

On the next button from MainWindow, I want to navigate to Page2. For that, I have following event handler for that button.

```
    private void Next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
        nav.Navigate(new Uri("Page2.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

**But call to NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this) is returning null.** What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please mention which exceptions are thrown, with details.

Comment: Pages are intended for use in Navigation applications (usually with Back and Forward buttons, e.g. Internet Explorer). Why you don't use a NavigationWindow or a Frame to host your pages?

Comment: @Tilman: added the error in bold in question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are requesting the Navegation service from a Window. WPF has two navigators: **NavigationWindow** and [**Frame**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame(v=vs.110).aspx). This kind of window and control have a NavigationService that handles content navigation.
For example in a window you can use a Frame as I show below:

```
<Window 
x:Class="NavigationSample.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300"
>
<StackPanel>
    <Frame x:Name="_mainFrame" />
</StackPanel>
```

And then, in your code begin, you can do something like this:

```
_mainFrame.Navigate(new Page1());
```

Another variant is using directly the NavigationService property:

```
_mainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Page1());
```

Check this link to see how GetNavegationService method work:[NavigationService.GetNavigationService Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.getnavigationservice(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can find more info here:[Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The answer is copied from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.getnavigationservice(v=vs.71) without any quotes, reference. I think this is plagiarism.

Comment: Hello @PaulSnow, I edited my answer some time ago trying to explain better how john smith could resolve his issue. Could you please undo your downvote?